# jQuery: how to get file name from fileupload control?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

What I want to implement is by clicking "attach a file", a file browser will be open to let user choose a file. I use jQuery to set onclick function of "attach a file", and set the opacity of a fileuload control to be 0. So it is like display:none. But I don't know how to get the file that user selected from fileupload control. Even don't know what event should be capture in the process. I want to save the file in a hidden div, so I can use it in backend code. Any method?

UPDATE: OK, I think it's better to describe my question more clearly. That is, how to get selected filename when you click open button in browser window? If in backend it is as easy as

```
string fileName=FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
```

I want to get the fileName in client using jQuery. Since I will use same fileUpload control to select multiple files, I need to add the filename into a hidden div when the browser window closed. Any idea?

Comment: Why not just use the built-in functionality that asp.net provides to accomplish this?

Comment: If you have the id: `var element = document.getElementById('fUpload'); ` then you can get the value no?

Comment: @JonH: I need to get the value whenever I select a file, because I'll use this control more than one times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file upload control renders as an INPUT of type file. If you retrieve its Value after change, it will hold the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comments if you have the ID you will have the value.

Place a file upload control on your form, then place an asp.net button or any button for that matter.

Then its a matter of:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  

            $("#btnUpload").click(function () {  

                var FileUpload = $("#MyFileUploadControl").val();  
   ... }
 }
```